# Exists holomorphic function on unit disk satisfying condition

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $g: [0, 2\pi] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function with $g(0) = g(2\pi)$. Does there exist a holomorphic function on the unit disk such that for each $\theta \in [0, 2\pi]$, we have$$\lim_{r \to 1-} \text{Re}[f(re^{i\theta})] = g(\theta)?$$

Comment: do you know the Cauchy integral formula ? and how it is related to  the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_problem as Soumya said

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your post as currently written is simply the statement of a problem. Such posts are discouraged here as they lack context. Please consider adding some details such as where this problem came from, what results you have seen that you think might be useful and any other thoughts on the problem.